# VBA keep track of which workbooks are open

Tags: vba, excel

**How can VBA keep track of which workbooks are open?**

I am writing a data mining macro that takes information from a variable number of workbooks. The user may choose what workbooks will be parsed via a userform. However, workbooks can be opened and closed while the userform is running.
So, how can my userform keep track of which workbooks are open, so that it can display them accurately.

Right now, I'm using a recursive function that calls itself with "Application.OnTime". I don't really like this solution for because it involves extra checks to see if the userform is still open, as well as having a delay because of whatever period the function is called at.

**Final:** *Combined solution from answers and comments*
userform code, requires a ListBox called WorkbookList, and a Textbox called FileTextBox

```
Private WithEvents App As Application

Public Sub WorkbookList_UpdateList()
    WorkbookList.Clear

    For Each Wb In Application.Workbooks
        WorkbookList.AddItem Wb.name
    Next Wb
End Sub

Private Sub WorkbookList_Change()
    If WorkbookList.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub

    key = WorkbookList.List(WorkbookList.ListIndex)

    For Each Wb In Application.Workbooks
        IsWorkBookOpen Wb.path
        If Wb.name = key Then FileTextbox.text = Wb.path
    Next Wb
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    WorkbookList_UpdateList
End Sub

Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    WorkbookList_UpdateList
End Sub

Private Sub App_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "WorkbookClosed"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
    WorkbookList_UpdateList
    UpdatePeriodicly
End Sub
```

module code (put this in a vba module):

```
'Code From: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=152892
Function IsUserFormLoaded(ByVal UFName As String) As Boolean
    Dim UForm As Object

    IsUserFormLoaded = False
    For Each UForm In VBA.UserForms
        If UForm.name = UFName Then
            IsUserFormLoaded = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function

Public Sub WorkbookClosed()
    If IsUserFormLoaded("InputForm") = False Then Exit Sub
    InputForm.WorkbookList_UpdateList
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use Application Events fgor this. E.g. see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx

Comment: Test if the workbook exists in the workbooks collection?

Comment: It's really a matter of how often you need to refresh that list. If you want as close to real-time as possible, use the event handler as Tim suggests, and have that handler simply refresh your listbox with the names from the `Workbooks` collection, each time a new workbook opens up (or closes).

Comment: @Tim Perfect! If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Siphor I'm not 100% sure what you mean. The main issue is knowing **when** to check if a workbook still exists or just came into existence. Or did you mean to improve efficiency of the "WorkbookList_UpdateList" sub? - rather than deleting all workbooks in the list and readding them, simply check if they still exist and then act accordingly

Comment: Use OnTime in the app-level workbook events. Set it for 1 second later. The collection object will be updated by then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Application Events fgor this.

E.g. see [cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx)

```
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application

Sub Init()
    Set app = Application 'start capturing events
End Sub


Private Sub app_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print "New"
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookBeforeClose(ByVal Wb As Workbook, Cancel As Boolean)
    Debug.Print "Before close: " & Wb.Name
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Debug.Print "Open: " & Wb.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think that this is an interesting script and something that might be useful for the problem your trying to solve.

```
Public Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)

Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False 'Workbook IS NOT
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True 'Workbook IS open
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

You can call this by doing something like this

```
Ret = IsWorkBookOpen("C:\test.xlsm")
 If Ret = True Then 'YOUR CODE HERE
```

Comment: Cool code, I will have a use for that later. However, my problem was figuring out how to run code after a workbook opens and after it closes

Comment: Also, I'm a little confused by the syntax. What does "For Input Lock Read As #ff" do? (if you know)